# Android Studio gives a gradle error when not 'Run as Administrator'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run it as administrator, it works fine. When I run it normally, it says

```
The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip' does not exist.
```

I couldn't find the cause or a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because Gradle building is attempted when the .gradle directory is in a location that requires administrator permission to access.

I encountered the same issue when the Gradle path in my Project structure > Sdk Location > Gradle Settings was not the default one, but pointed to a directory in my Java environment that could only be accessed with administrator privileges.

To fix this, I set the Gradle path in Project structure > Sdk Location > Gradle Settings to C:/Users/nameoftheuser. This way, the Gradle versions are downloaded in the .gradle directory created in that location, which can be easily accessed by the user without requiring administrator privileges to run Android Studio.

To ensure this solution works properly, I also set the environment variable of Java as shown in this screenshot:
[Envinroment Variable of Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewMNk.png)

I hope this solution helps you too.
Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Shouldn't the AS setup set the path the right way ? AS should ask for permission if needed. I don't understand that Gradle currently needs admin on every build. This has to be a bug.

The user path sucks. I want to be able to use a multi-user operating system as a multi-user operating system.

Comment: I understand your frustration, I have personally solved with placing correctly the gradle build path to a position accessible even if we don't have admin permission. To all my colleagues all of this stuff worked fine, so maybe depends on the place where AS is installed and where it put the version of Gradle that you are using to build your code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be environment variables issue and possibly due to downloading / installing a new version of gradle.

- if desired, download latest gradle here: https://gradle.org/releases/
- on Windows, it will install in C:\Program Files\gradle-8.x
- if you have multiple versions installed, you might create a common linked folder e.g. "gradle" in C:\Program Files

> ```
> if exist "c:\Program Files\gradle" rmdir "C:\Program Files\gradle"
> mklink /d "C:\Program Files\gradle" "C:\Program Files\gradle-8.5"
> ```

Edit environment variables:

- Set GRADLE_USER_HOME to %USERPROFILE%\.gradle
- Add C:\Program Files\gradle\bin to PATH

Launch new cmd and check gradle version

> gradle -v